# Time mismatching in admin section

Tags: python, django, heroku, time, timezone

I am buiding an app in Django, it is hosted on Heroku.
My problem started after I had to reset my database on Heroku.

[image]

The app gets some data via API and then saves it into a model, with the time and date of the record.
This model shows the time and date in its objects name.

```
Last_update_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now )

def __str__(self): 
    return  "%s --- [ %s ]"  %  (self.Target_area_input_data.Name, datetime.strftime(self.Last_update_time, "%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%Y") )
```

The information is then displayed in a template.

The time displayed in the template is correct (it corresponds to the time displayed by my pc clock, 22:33 in the example), but when I access my model in Django admin, it is two hours earlier (20:33 in the example).

[image]

The strange thing is that when I access the object fields view, the time is right (22:33 in the example).

[image]

What could be the problem?

In my settings I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
USE_TZ = True
```

I tryed to change

```
USE_TZ = False
```

only resulting in the time in the object fields view being two hours earlier (20:33 in the example), like the others, and the message "you are 2 hours ahead from the server time" appearing.

**UPDATE:**

Maybe I was wrong and the database reset has nothing to do with this error.

However, I am sure that since I have in settings:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
USE_TZ = True
```

The database shows correct time for its objects, even if the view of the model objects list of Django admin shows the time in UTC. (I am not sure if there is a way to set the timezone for time appearing inside the name of the model objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was wrong: the database reset has nothing to do with this error.

It turns out that Django natively does not allow to change timezone for admin, because all time data used by admins is meant to have the same landmark. It's like all admins should be using the same unit of measurement.

However, [as suggested here](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52710743.shtml), one could set a timezone for each admin user, so that every admin sees the timedate data of the admin section expressed according to his/her timezone.